# MVC: Controller knows about persistence?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Just getting started with MVC, long-time WebForms experience.

I don't want to decorate my entities with UI-oriented properties like "display name" or "required", plus a lot of them have more methods and properties than I care to expose on a view.

So I'm experimenting with ViewModels that wrap, or in other ways interact with the actual entities in my system. What I don't like is how the Controller has to know to query a repository and then instantiate a ViewModel to wrap the entity it got back.

What are best-practices for a controller to interact with ViewModels without having to know how they're persisted? All the examples I see talk directly to EntityFramework or other ORM's.

I was thinking about static methods on the ViewModel classes that take an IRepository reference and an ID to load and return the ViewModel. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DependencyInjection to pass your Repository to your controller.

```
public HomeController
{
    private readonly IHomeRepository repo;

    public HomeController(IHomeRepository repository)
    {
        repo = repository;
    }
}
```

Then inside your action methods, get the items, and create your ViewModels from those objects.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // IEnumerable models are bad, but this is just a quick demo.
    var viewModels = repo.GetWidgets().Select(w => new WidgetModel(w));

    return View("Index", viewModels);
}
```

Comment: So as a best-practice it is ok for the Controller to know how the ViewModels are related to the entities - and to get the entity out of a ViewModel to save it?

Comment: Yes, the controller's job is to get the data, and give it to the view. The view only knows about the models. You don't want to have the model do that work, because then you're polluting what is for display purposes with business logic. Your models should be as light as possible.

Comment: i agree that ViewModels shouldn't know either... I guess since a Controller is orchestrating a View to a Model it makes sense for it to know where that Model came from. Thank you!

Comment: @n8wrl - Your definition of "model" is a lot more broad.  In MVC, the model knows nothing about persistence, but does know about display properties.  The "model" is actually a ViewModel.  Because MVC is a presentational pattern.  The business layer will have its own model, as will the data layer.  You have mapping classes (or technologies like AutoMapper) to map between the layers.

Comment: @krillgar: Thank you, that makes sense and is what I had in mind. The dots that didn't connect for me was that it is ok for the controller to know about the relationship between the UI ViewModel and the entity 'model' and its persistence. That is, the repository. Thank you!